# Search and count specific words from a text file

Tags: c#

i would like to search for a specific set of words (or for now one word) which is "Jude" this is my current code, i can read the file, it separates the words but its just comparing them to a word is the problem. (at the moment it is rigged up to just count words and the output is correct).

Many Thanks
-Fred

```
      String theLine;
        string theFile;
        int counter = 0;
        string[] fields = null;
        string delim = " ,.";

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a filename:");
        theFile = Console.ReadLine();


        System.IO.StreamReader sr =
               new System.IO.StreamReader(theFile);

        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            theLine = sr.ReadLine();
            theLine.Trim();
            fields = theLine.Split(delim.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            counter += fields.Length;
        }


        sr.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("The word count is {0}", counter);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: This looks like an assignment. Are you allowed to use Linq?

Comment: it is an assignment but only a part of it, and im not sure sorry.

Comment: This seems like what regex with word boundaries are for...

Comment: ahh yes i am using linq

Comment: The least change to your existing code would be `counter += fields.Count(x => x == "Jude");`

Comment: When you say "search for a specific set of words" what do you mean? Do you mean count the number of occurrences?

Comment: yes exactly, searching a file for it :)

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ, you can enumerate the lines of the file, then count the number of occurrences of your word or words in each line and sum the counts together:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a filename:");
var theFile = Console.ReadLine();

var delim = " ,.".ToCharArray();
var countWords = new HashSet(new[] { "Jude" }.Select(w => w.ToUpperInvariant()));
var count = File.ReadLines(theFile).Select(l => l.Split(delim, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Count(w => countWords.Contains(w.ToUpperInvariant()))).Sum();
Console.WriteLine("The word count is {0}", count);
```

If you prefer @Dai's regex pattern approach, you can use it to count the occurrences in each line, still using LINQ to process the lines and sum the counts:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a filename:");
var theFile = Console.ReadLine();

var delim = " ,.".ToCharArray();
var countWords = new[] { "Jude" };
var wordPattern = new Regex(@"\b(?:"+String.Join("|", countWords)+@")\b", RegexOptions.Compiled|RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var count = File.ReadLines(theFile).Select(l => wordPattern.Matches(l).Count).Sum();
Console.WriteLine("The word count is {0}", count);
```

Comment: `source.ToHashSet()` is not part of `System.Linq` but you can do `new HashSet( source )`. You shouldn't use `ToLower()` for case-insensitive comparisons because it isn't culture-invariant (and not all text normalizes to lower-case correctly, see "The Turkish I-problem"). You should use `new HashSet( source, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase )` instead.

Comment: @Dai My extension snuck in there. You must pass a type to `new HashSet` in which case it would be `new HashSet<string>(source, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`. I prefer using `ToUpperInvariant()` if you are worried about it.

Answer (score 1):

- Avoid new object allocations inside tight loops, in particular:

  - Don't use `String.Split()` as it causes excess string allocation
  - Also avoid calling `ToCharArray()` too - you can just cache the results.
- Use `using()` to ensure `IDisposable` objects are always disposed.

I recommend using a Regex instead:

```
Regex regex = new Regex( @"\bJude\b", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );

Int32 count = 0;
using( StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader( theFile ) )
{
    String line;
    while( ( line = rdr.ReadLine() ) != null )
    {
        count += regex.Matches( line ).Count;
    } 
}
```

The `\b` escape matches a "word-boundary", such as the start and end of strings and punctuation, so it will match "Jude" in the following examples: `"Jude"`, `"Jude foo"`, `"Foo Jude"`, `"Hello. Jude."` but not `"JudeJude"`.

Comment: and, for a list of words, `"\\b(" + String.Join("|", stringsList) + ")\\b"`

Comment: Oh hai @Nyerguds - how's the Tiberian Dawn hackery going? :D

Comment: lol, hardly the place to discuss that, but, kind of on hold, but I got hold of a Japanese C&C95, which has the fun feature to use an _image_ as mission briefing, and I think I wanna port that :)

Comment: C# doesn't have `CaseInsensitive`, it uses `IgnoreCase` I believe.